# dividing by two in binary numbers

Tags: binary, divide

how can I divide a binary number (in 2 complement) by 2 . 
 
I've tried bit shifting but I have a problem with negative odd numbers, how can I solve it? 
for example :

```
(-7/2) 11001/2 => (shifts the number one place to the right) => 11100 (-4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use after the . ? Like this?

```
        1 0011 . 1000
Part    1 2    3 4
```

Part 1: Negative number
Part 2: Makes 3
Part 3: Separate by .
part 4: Makes 0.5

The negative part works like:

.1000   = 0.5
.0100   = 0.25
.1100   = 0.75
.0010   = 0.125

So instead of multiply by 2 to shift to left. You can do a divide by 2 to the right. So after the dot /2 and before the dot x2.

Hope you can use this information.

Comment: I need the complete part of the result : 5/2 = 2 
-7/2 = -3